# Linq dropping rows from stored procedure and inline query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

has anybody seen where linq drops rows from a query?

if I query the data base

select * from staging_flowrates where flowdate between '4/16/2012' and '4-22-2012'

I get back 29 records, which is what I would expect.

if I call a this  procedure in linq i get 25 records. I've done it so many different ways and they all return results less than 29

```
List<weekly_invoice_dataResult> meterdata = flowRateDB.weekly_invoice_data(173,    date.AddDays(-8), date.AddDays(-2)).ToList();}
```

or

```
var meters = from c in flowRateDB.staging_flowrates
             where c.FlowDate >= date.AddDays(-8) && c.FlowDate <= date.AddDays(-2)
             select c;
```

all these return 25 rows, but if I go back to ADO and do a count I get 29. I've been using linq for about 6 years and I have not noticed this ever.

any ideas?

Matt

Comment: How do you get `date`? could it have a time component!=0? perhaps try the query with `(new Date(2012,4,24))` instead of date

Comment: I think @HugoRune has got something here. The discrepancy can also be caused by non-unique key values in the database (of the field that L2S knows as primary key).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start SQL Server Profiler and capture the exact SQL executed. Take this SQL and execute it yourself in SSMS. My guess is that the query executed is wrong in some way and you will be able to see why that is.

One thing is for sure: LINQ is not dropping rows. The reason for that is the SQL executed.